# How do you get a PHP page with arguments to point to itself?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make a page where, when a form is submitted, it returns to the page from where the form was called from. Normally, I'd just set the form action to `basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);` and it would work fine. The problem that I'm having is that the form on this page is now being called from a url like `www.yaddayadda.com/article.php?id=4`, so when I use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` it only returns `article.php`. Is there anyway to make it return the variables after the script name as well?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. If you print_r() all $_SERVER variables, you'll see there're several good candidates. The main difference comes when your script goes through CGI, gateways or URL rewriting (such as Apache's mod_rewrite). I believe REQUEST_URI is pretty safe.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` or use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` that combines both.

It's often useful to do a `print_r($_SERVER);` or `phpinfo();` to find out what your specific environment has to offer in terms of server variables.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` or `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as stated [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).